# IOS Getting an XML file from resources to treat it in c++

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

I'm doing a c++ program that needs to parse an XML file to get some properties. (EDIT: i'm doing an iOS app --> that's maybe a good thing to know)

EDIT : its a plist file (I dunno if it changes something)

(I'm using Libxml2). I got the path to the file via

```
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"env-cfg" ofType:@"plist"];
    std::string* ret_path = new std::string([path UTF8String]);
    return ret_path;
```

when I try to print the content of the file I don't have an XML file anymore. It prints me something like this

```
    bplist00\321[environment\241\324 .... etc
```

The thing I need is the original XML file to parse it with my c++ code . I know that i can get the datas from the file in Obj-c quite easily but i'd really like to make this part in c++. Does anyone knows is there a way to parse that XML file ? (without using Obj-c)

I don't know if i'm clear

[EDIT] : I've change the file type in Xcode to XML file. I don't have a weird output anymore when i print it, as said in a comments, it was a binary (dunno why it has to change when you run the project) but anyway i'm still interested if someones know if it is possible from c++ to get the xml file from the binary form or if there is a way to parse the binary

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Is it a binary plist?

Comment: Is it a *binary* plist?  Go to the command line and see what the `file` command thinks it is.

Comment: ho sorry i didn't know that they were different type of plist, and no, it isn't suppose to be a binary plist. But i get after compilation, it becomes one, maybe ? is there a function or something to convert it back to a xml file ?

Comment: seems like when i put it as a normal xml file in Xcode, it works, i can parse it.
My problem is kinda solved but i'm still interested in a possibility to use a regular info plist

Comment: The XML version of the file is a "regular" plist file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `.plist` file is in binary format.  Convert it to XML using this command on the command line:

```
$ plutil -convert xml1 env-cfg.plist
```

Comment: Yes i do think so too, but i'm parsing it after compilation time, its originally a info plist XML

Comment: There really is no reason to put any effort into answering questions on this site.  I've had enough of it.